# button click binding and view model encapsulation

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I want to implement simple toggle button functionality using Ractivejs. Here is the code:

```
function MyViewModel(model) {
    var self = this;
    self.value = false;
    self.toggleValue = function () {
        self.value = !self.value; //this will probably not update view, but it is not the point here
    };
}

var viewModel = new MyViewModel(model);
var ractive = new Ractive({ el: 'mydiv', template: '#mytemplate', data: viewModel });
```

and here is my template

```
<script id='mytemplate' type='text/ractive'>
    <p>Value: {{value}}</p>
    <button type="button">Toggle</button>
</script>
```

How do I call MyViewModel.toggleValue function when the button is clicked? For now I know two options:

1. I can add `on-click='toggle("value")'` to `button` element. However, let's assume that my toggleValue function may be somewhat more complicated, so this solution is not enough.
2. I can add `on-click='toggleValue'` to `button` element. But then I need to add this code:

   ractive.on('toggleValue', function () {
       viewModel.toggleValue();
   });

which means that:

1. I am writing code that has to know about my view model outside this view model. This is bad from encapsulation perspective.
2. It also means that `toggleValue` is global for Ractive instance and not view model specific which means maintenance issues sooner or later.
3. It is not in any way better than using jQuery `$("button").click(myFunction)`.

So how do I do it correctly? I need equivalent of KnockoutJs' `data-bind="click: toggleValue"`.

EDIT: For working code have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/xak5k8rd/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create that type of syntax by adding a prototype method to Ractive:

```
Ractive.prototype.bind = function(context, method){

    // if using < 0.6.1 you may encounter bug {{this}} or {{.}} not returning model root
    //context = context || this.data

    context[method].call(context, this)
}
```

then consume in your template as:

```
<button type="button" on-click="bind(this, 'toggleValue')">Toggle</button>
<ul>
{{#tab}}
    <li on-click="bind(this, 'click')">{{val}}</li>
{{/tab}}
</ul>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/obdk4k2o/2/

EDITED: Added context to bind function. Note any template model value could be passed, but `this` is certainly handy for lists.

EDITED: In `0.6.1`, method calls have access to `this.event` meaning the keypath is available as well as the context (so it doesn't need to be passed in).

The method becomes:

```
Ractive.prototype.bind = function(method){
    var context = this.event.context,
        keypath = this.event.keypath
    context[method].call(context, this, keypath)
}
```

Template is:

```
<button type="button" on-click="bind('toggleValue')">Toggle</button>
<ul>
{{#tab}}
    <li on-click="bind('click')">{{val}}</li>
{{/tab}}
</ul>
```

And in your viewmodel:

```
self.click=function(ractive, keypath){
    ractive.set(keypath + ".val", !self.val);
    alert('click');
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/obdk4k2o/6/

Comment: That could be a step in the right direction but we are not there yet. Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/obdk4k2o/1/ - this time we have nested view models and want to call `click` function from the subviewmodel (RowViewModel). I had a look at what gets passed to the `bind` function and I do not see anything that could indicate the RowViewModel object is the current context.

Comment: It's geting better - I wish I could upvote twice :-) But there is one more issue - in the click function I would like to manipulate the view model eg. change the value of `val`. Please have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/obdk4k2o/5/ - right now in `ractive.set` I need to use full keypath to my variable which means that my RowViewModel needs to know about MyViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

I think that second variant isn't wrong. 
View has element, view propagates some event when someone clicks on the button. 
View doesn't even know that someone has listener for that event, and doesn't care if someone actually have that kind of a listener.

IMO you just make yourself confused by naming event with respect to your business logic. But that's wrong, IMO. 
View should throw a general event, like "A button was clicked, and I don't care if anybody do want to do something about it". 
IMO, working through the event is enough for decoupling layers from each other.

Like this:

Template:

```
<script id='mytemplate' type='text/ractive'>
    <p>Value: {{value}}</p>
    <button type="button" on-tap="UserMakeSomeAction">Toggle</button>
</script>
```

JS:

```
ractive.on('UserMakeSomeAction', function () { viewModel.toggleValue(); });
```

P.S. Besides, your example with KnockoutJs is so much about coupling presentation layer with behavior layer. Your view should know exactly what method should be present at controller, to know it's name, and to call it. IMO, event-based propagation is much better.

Comment: First, I am assuming MVVM pattern here (which may be wrong). Second, the view has to know about its view model - for one the view does know that the view model has a field called `value` - so that the view can display it. Then why should the view suddenly 'forget' about its knowledge of view model when it comes to events? It does not make the view any more independent and it introduces additinal layer of complexity that can be a source of errors.

Comment: Ractive tries to be a library agnostic, but helpful, to any particular web m-v-x-whatever denomination :). There was some discussion about whether the function calls should be model-based (attractive in its symmetry IMO) but controller methods won out thus far. Probably because ractive has data manipulation methods. Please feel free to jump in on [google group](groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ractive-js) or [github](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues) for discussion directions and visions.